# Android Studio - Cannot view code for activity_main.xml

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and when I try to add code to activity_main.xml, I only see the design and blueprint. How do I get to the code?

I have attached a screenshot of what I see.

[image]

Comment: Click `Text` on the bottom left of the UI designer window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to go to **xml** file. or right click on ***hello world*** text and chek the last option in the list go to **xml.**

Answer (score 5):

In android studio version 3.6.1 they have replaced the design and code buttons to the top right of the layout window.
**See in the top right corner of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7BX5.png) image, where "code" is showing up**:

[image: Android Studio 3.6.1 screenshot: Code, Split, Design position]

Answer (score 0):

Click right and click on go to code option.